# How to upgrade moodle version using cli/git?

Tags: php, git, moodle, moodle-api

I have a moodle site which is maintained in a personal github repository. When moodle releases a new moodle version, I need to replace files manually to upgrade moodle version in my personal repository. Is there any way, in which I can automate the manual task with cli or git by connecting moodle official repository with my personal repository? What is the best way to upgrade moodle version in my scenario?

Comment: I don't know enough about Moodle but if you're using composer, can you not just alter the dependencies version to release version and run `composer install --no-dev`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, fork a repository(**moodle**) to create a copy of the repository(**personal**).

Get

Then click on **fetch upstream** to keep the branch up-to-date with the upstream repository(**moodle**). See below screenshot
[image]

Run git pull command for update code with a particular branch

```
git pull [remote] [branch]
```

Comment: But this way i can not make multiple fork of the same repo in a single github account. Because in my case i have multiple moodle projects of different clients so they have different code bases.